# как в проекте laravel 5 сделать определитель платформы?

Tags: php, laravel

как в проекте laravel 5 сделать определитель платформы?
Т.е. есть две кнопки apple, android, чтоб нажимая с мобильного браузера с этого сайта на кнопку apple выводило что-то типа "Нажмите на ссылку, соответствующей Вашей операционной системе", если у меня на телефоне стоит платформа android и наоборот.

Comment: Вопрос зачем? Есть же стили сss, scss & less. Если там что-то нужно запустить, то сначала нужно сделать view, потом пустой контроллер и написать в него, если get android, делать тото, в противном случае тото. В остальном https://laracasts.com/

Comment: Я сделал самое тяжелое, что может быть в жизни, за тебя, google.com, [jenssegers/agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orange_shadow скинул ссылку на github, где используется в проекте данный определитель платформы https://github.com/jenssegers/agent